# Given complete graph, find optimal path with two costs on each edge

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

We are given complete graph, such that each edge has two costs $a \text{ and } b$. We should find path that passes through each node once and has minimum total cost. Cost of a path is the maximum of both of the sums $a$ and $b$ of the edges laying on the edges crossed on the path.

One person told me that this is easily solvable by taking the maximum of $a \text { and } b$ for each edge and then using the dynamic programming technique storing the  final index and the bitmask of visited nodes. I couldn't find a counter test case, however I'm not sure if this is correct approach.

Comment: Can you add a reference to the original problem?

Comment: I don't have reference this time, since this was a problem I saw at one programming camp, however there wasn't any resource mentioned and the problems are not being published online.

Comment: What is "the maximum of both of the sums  and  of the edges laying on the edges crossed on the path"? Can you add a simple non-trivial example in the question??

Comment: Say you choose one path (that goes through each node once) of the complete graph. On this path keep two variables, one is the sum of all a values on this path, and the other one is the sum of all b variables on this path. Then the cost of this path is the maximum of those two sums.